# Subscripting a soup object's <h3> tag text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the number of bedrooms and bathrooms from the house listings on zoopla.co.uk. I have subscripted the h3 tag's text. It's giving me what I want, but:

1. Should I be trying to scrape the text via divs instead?
2. Will it be a real integer or a number character in the csv?

python

```
my_url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine'

house_listings = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"listing-results-right clearfix"})

listings = house_listings[3] # item 4 for prototyping

house_bedrooms = listings.h3.text[1]
print(house_bedrooms)
# 4

house_bathrooms = listings.h3.text[3]
print(house_bathrooms)
# 1
```

Edit for @bigbounty

```
style = re.findall('(?<=bed ).*(?= for)', str(listings.h2.a.text))

distance = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', str(listings.ul.li.text))

if style:
    print(f"Type of House - {style}")
if distance:
    print(f"Distance from Station - {distance}")


# Output:

# Type of House - ['detached house']
# Distance from Station - ['1.2']
```

object's html

```
<div class="listing-results-right clearfix">
<div class="agent_logo">
<img alt="Marketed by Yopa" class="lazy" data-src="https://st.zoocdn.com/zoopla_static_agent_logo_(654234).png"/>
<noscript><img alt="Marketed by Yopa" src="https://st.zoocdn.com/zoopla_static_agent_logo_(654234).png"/></noscript>
</div>
<a class="listing-results-price text-price" href="/for-sale/details/55889526">


        £325,000


</a>
<h3 class="listing-results-attr">
<span class="num-icon num-beds" title="4 bedrooms"><span class="interface"></span>4</span> <span class="num-icon num-baths" title="1 bathroom"><span class="interface"></span>1</span> <span class="num-icon num-reception" title="2 reception rooms"><span class="interface"></span>2</span>
</h3>
<h2 class="listing-results-attr">
<a href="/for-sale/details/55889526" style="text-decoration:underline;">4 bed detached house for sale</a>
<span class="listing-results-just-added">Just added</span>
</h2>
<span><a class="listing-results-address" href="/for-sale/details/55889526">Maxted Road, Erdington, Birmingham B23</a></span>
<div class="listing-results-attr">
</div>
<p>

                    An immaculately presented family home that will highly impress all viewers. Features include a full length lounge, Separate Dining Room, stylish fitted kitchen, Ground Floor WC, four double bedrooms, stunning bathroom suite, detached Garage, carport, ...

                </p>
<div class="nearby_stations_schools clearfix">
<ul>
<li class="clearfix">
<span class="interface nearby_stations_schools_national_rail_station" title="Erdington"></span>
<span class="nearby_stations_schools_name" title="Erdington">Erdington</span>


            (1.2 miles)

        </li>
<li class="clearfix">
<span class="interface nearby_stations_schools_national_rail_station" title="Chester Road"></span>
<span class="nearby_stations_schools_name" title="Chester Road">Chester Road</span>


            (1.3 miles)

        </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;">
<small>Note: Distances are straight line measurements</small>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Source**
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine

Comment: What's a `true integer`?

Comment: Well, I just mean a real integer instead of a number character.

Comment: Question 1 - you can use divs so that you get more control over the data gets extracted and also it helps extracting other elements if needed.
Question 2 - if the type is int in the dataframe then it will be an int in the csv as well

Comment: Thanks @bigbounty. So could you please post an example using my source to access the bedroom and bathroom values with the conventional method with divs you are referring to? Much appreciated.

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = 'https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/b23/?page_size=100&q=B23&radius=0&results_sort=newest_listings&search_source=refine'

res = requests.get(my_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

lis = soup.find("ul", class_="listing-results clearfix js-gtm-list").find_all("li", class_="srp clearfix")

for li in lis:
    print("https://www.zoopla.co.uk{}".format(li.find("a", class_="listing-results-price text-price")["href"]))
    beds = li.find("span", class_="num-beds")
    receps = li.find("span", class_="num-reception")
    baths = li.find("span", class_="num-baths")
    if beds:
        print(f"Number of Beds - {beds.get_text(strip=True)}")
    if receps:
        print(f"Number of Reception - {receps.get_text(strip=True)}")
    if baths:
        print(f"Number of Baths - {baths.get_text(strip=True)}")
    print("-"*25)
```

Output:

```
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55907272
Number of Beds - 1
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55904182
Number of Beds - 3
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55900453
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55889526
Number of Beds - 4
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55887661
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55886616
Number of Beds - 3
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55882047
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55865458
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55865457
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55865414
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55865302
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 3
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55852984
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55850696
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55845249
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 3
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55064067
Number of Beds - 4
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55812936
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55790928
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55788734
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55779396
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55771988
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55767996
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 3
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55763381
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55758093
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55755484
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55750535
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/51569378
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55722643
Number of Beds - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55716130
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55714653
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55713263
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55682695
Number of Beds - 4
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55673718
Number of Beds - 4
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55670304
Number of Beds - 4
Number of Reception - 3
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55660378
Number of Beds - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55659472
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55645273
Number of Beds - 4
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55636480
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55627146
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55607862
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55597104
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54223579
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55522317
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55480779
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55453635
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55453634
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55419103
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55418059
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/53202677
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55387036
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55358482
Number of Beds - 3
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55352507
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55331187
Number of Beds - 4
Number of Reception - 3
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55308436
Number of Beds - 1
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55307910
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55297074
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55248700
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55235358
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/50515317
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55149715
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/53392656
Number of Beds - 1
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55167652
Number of Beds - 1
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55166615
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55158568
Number of Beds - 3
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/51795614
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/53622784
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55097614
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/55066083
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54374337
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54973550
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54937429
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54854357
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54809703
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54677354
Number of Beds - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54640976
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54626916
Number of Beds - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54581499
Number of Beds - 1
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/48050331
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54447355
Number of Beds - 3
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54417038
Number of Beds - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/49837014
Number of Beds - 1
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54246675
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54243533
Number of Beds - 2
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 1
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54179773
Number of Beds - 3
Number of Reception - 2
Number of Baths - 2
-------------------------
https://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/54151517
Number of Beds - 6
Number of Reception - 1
Number of Baths - 6
-------------------------
```

Comment: That is a work of art. Amazing. Thanks. p.s. I also have `house_type = re.findall('(?<=bed ).*(?= for)', str(listings.h2.a.text))` prints: `['detached house']`. Should I be doing that part your way as well or is it better with my regex?

Comment: I also tried this: `distance = li.find("li", class_="clearfix")` then `print(f"Distance from Station - {distance.get_text(strip=True)}")` which gave me `Distance from Station - Erdington(0.2 miles)`. But I would like just to extract the `0.2`.

Comment: I also tried this which gave me just the data but in an array/list. Is that ok? `distance = li.find("li", class_="clearfix")` then `regex_distance = re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', str(distance))` then `print(f"Distance from Station - {regex_distance}")` which gave me `Distance from Station - ['0.2']`. Is that list ok or should I be trying to print just the string `0.2`? Or will pandas take care of that?